# Spring can't find Service or Repository beans to Autowire

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I'm trying to run spring boot with spring data as basically as possible with swing.

However, even though all seems to be properly configured, when I try to run it, I get an error message saying it couldn't find my Service bean.

```java
package db.westworld.dao;

import db.westworld.entities.RobotEntity;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface RobotRepository extends CrudRepository<RobotEntity, Integer> {
}
```

```java
package db.westworld.service;

import db.westworld.entities.RobotEntity;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface IRobotService {
    Optional<RobotEntity> findById(int id);
}
```

```java
package db.westworld.service;

import db.westworld.dao.RobotRepository;
import db.westworld.entities.RobotEntity;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class RobotService implements IRobotService {

    private final RobotRepository robotRepository;

    @Autowired
    RobotService(RobotRepository robotRepository) {
        this.robotRepository = robotRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<RobotEntity> findById(int id) {
        return robotRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public void saveRobot(RobotEntity robot) {
        robotRepository.save(robot);
    }
}
```

```java
package db.westworld;

import db.westworld.view.RegisterRobot;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;

import java.awt.*;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WestworldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder(RegisterRobot.class).headless(false).run(args);
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            var ex = ctx.getBean(RegisterRobot.class);
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

```java
package db.westworld.view;

import db.westworld.entities.RobotEntity;
import db.westworld.service.RobotService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Controller
public class RegisterRobot extends JDialog {
private RobotService robotService;

    @Autowired
    public void setRobotService (RobotService robotService) {
        this.robotService = robotService;
    }
    private void onOK() {
        RobotEntity robot = new RobotEntity();
        robot.setCreatedAt(new Date());
        robot.setId(1);
        robotService.saveRobot(robot);
        dispose();
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Parameter 0 of method setRobotService in db.westworld.view.RegisterRobot required a bean of type 'db.westworld.service.RobotService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'db.westworld.service.RobotService' in your configuration.
```

(the JDialog implementation just includes the basics)

The same also happens when I try to autowire the repository. 
Also, in case needed, here's my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>    <groupId>db</groupId>
    <artifactId>westworld</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>westworld</name>
    <description>westworldSpringBoot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: @Andreas yes that worked!! Thanks a lot, can you write it as an answer here?

Comment: Notes: (1) It's not idiomatic in Java to prefix interfaces with `I`. (2) Don't wrap a repository interface for the sole purpose of delegating everything to it. (3) If your dependency is required, use constructor injection instead of setter injection. (4) Instead of doing anything with `getBean`, implement `CommandLineRunner`.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- what's the correct way of naming interfaces?

About the interfaces, I'm just doing what I found out after some extensive looking in the internet, what would be the correct way of doing it? I thought I needed the repo to extend the CrudRepository so it could generate the methods for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter to `new SpringApplicationBuilder()` must be the class annotate with `@SpringBootApplication`, as shown in every Spring Boot example I've ever seen, e.g. [Create an Application class](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#_create_an_application_class) in the "Getting Started - Building an Application with Spring Boot" guide.

Comment: It doesn't have to be specifically, but it has to be an `@Configuration` entry point from which Spring can figure out how to create a context, and by convention it's the Boot launcher class.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Actually, it's the lack of component scanning that is the real issue here, i.e. that all the other components aren't loaded by Spring, hence the "bean not found" error. `@SpringBootApplication` implicitly defines the package for component scanning.